# How can I check if Python´s ConfigParser has a section or not?

Tags: application-development, python, configuration, quickly

How can I check if the ConfigParser mainfile has a section or not,

And if it don´t then add a new section to it?

I am trying with this code:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

#if the config file don´t has the section 'globel', then add it to the config-file 
if not config.has_section("globel"):                                
       config.add_section("globel")
       config.set("globel", "settings", "someting")
       config.write(open("/tmp/myfile.conf", "w"))

       print "The new sestion globel is now added!!"
#else just return the the value of globle->settings
else:
       config.read("/tmp/myfile.conf")
       print "else... globle->settings == "+config.get("globel", "settings")
```

Comment: Global? (spelling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the config file before checking for the section.
Put the line

```
config.read("/tmp/myfile.conf")
```

just after

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
```

It's no error if the config file doesn't exist yet.